# Android Modeless Popupwindow

Tags: android, popupwindow, modeless

I can't seem to create a modeless popupwindow in Android. I can create a popupwindow just fine, and it will receive events. However, what I need is for it to receive its events, and if the user clicks outside the popup window, the activity receives events as per normal.

I don't really want to use a dialog, and I'm looking for a look where a control pops up, and the user can choose to click on that or choose to click on something else in the activity.

I've been reading about FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, but I can't seem to get this wot work with a popupwindow.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to show a pop up window? A sub activity or a dialog or a popup menu?

Comment: are you working purely native or using javascript API like PhoneGap or Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example/library

https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView

An other option that i use in my projects is:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.Activity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

and catch the user selections with onActivityResult(...)